# Cordova app storage

Tags: android, ios, cordova, local-storage, cordova-plugins

I am new to cordova app development and I am not sure how to approach this application workflow.

The workflow is that: 
  1. user download and installs the app
  2. he ca use basic feature without registration 
During this time (unregistered user with app installed) on backend we have to track the user activity and in case he register using email to upgrade his profile and keep his previous activity.

A solution to this will be to generate a user GUID on mobile when user first install the app. Send it to backend and use this as a future reference of the user.

Where can I store this GUID to be reliable and not to be cleared by the browser/application cache. If user clears the application data I would like the GUID to stay.

It will be great if this setting will stay if user upgrade the app or uninstall and reinstall later.

V Best,
Radu

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't storage data in a device when the user uninstall it, but if you still want it, check this plugin:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

You can save in different locations, even in the external storage of the device, which doesn't get deleted when the app is unistalled

Answer (score 0):

[Cordova unique device id plugin](https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID) generate a UUID that remains the same after app uninstall and works on iOS and Android.

On iOS it generates a UUID and store it in the [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html).

On Android it concatenates various IDs unique to the device but needs the `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.